# Lattice with property weaker than distributivity

Tags: lattice-orders

Consider a (finite?) lattice $L$ with bottom $\perp$.

Suppose that I want the following property to hold:

*For every $x_1,\dots,x_n,y\in L$,*
$$ \bigwedge_i x_i = \perp $$
*implies*
$$ \bigwedge_i (y \vee x_i) = y\;. $$

Does it have a name? Clearly this property is true if $L$ is distributive. But is it actually weaker?
Is it satisfied by other "famous" type of lattices? Has it been studied?

Comment: This seems to me to be a particular case of the _restricted distributive laws_ of canonical extensions of bounded lattices, as defined in the paper _Bounded lattices expansions_, by Mai Gehrke and John Harding (Journal of Algebra, vol 238). The definition is in the statement of Lemma 3.2. The reason I think it might apply is that each singleton is, of course, an upwardly directed set. However, that doesn't seem to be true for all choices of elements of the lattice. Nevertheless, if I'm not confusing things, the set of open elements is a sublattice, and it should apply to that one.

Answer (score 6):

**Clearly this property is true if L is distributive. But is it actually weaker?**

Yes, it is weaker. Your  condition, namely

$$
(\bigwedge x_i=\bot)\Rightarrow (\bigwedge (y\vee x_i) = y)
$$
is a quasiidentity in the language with symbols $\vee, \wedge, \bot$. It fails in $M_3$ and $N_5$, so a lattice satisfying this condition will not have any minimal distributivity failures involving $\bot$. But any lattice with a new least element $\bot$ adjoined will satisfy this quasiidentity. That is, the ordinal sum $\{\bot\}+L$ satisfies this condition for any $L$.

If you alter your condition so that it says 
$$
(\bigwedge x_i=z)\Rightarrow (\bigwedge (y\vee x_i) = (y\vee z)),
$$
then you get distributivity, but you should not expect to get distributivity with a condition that depends in an essential way on a reference to the bottom element.