# A property of complete lattices, and its relation to continuity

Tags: reference-request, lattice-orders

I am interested in complete lattices $L$ (with least element $0$ and greatest element 1) satisfying either of the following properties.

Property 1 (stronger):  Given any *totally ordered* subset $I \subseteq L$ and any $a \in L$,

$$a \wedge \left(\bigvee_{i\in I} i \right )= \bigvee_{i\in I} (a \wedge i).$$

Property 2 (weaker):  Given any *totally ordered* subset $I \subseteq L$ and any $a \in L$ such that $a \wedge i = 0$  for all $i \in I$,

$$a \wedge \left(\bigvee_{i\in I} i \right )= \bigvee_{i\in I} (a \wedge i) = 0.$$

Questions 1: Are there names for these properties?  They seem related to continuity.

Question 2: Does the answer to question 1 change if $L$ has one or both of the following properties: (a) $L$ is modular, (b) $\bigvee J=1$ for some join-irredundant family of atoms $J$?

Note 2: This question is similar to  [the one asked here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2050661/643459)

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

Property 1: At least one author (see third paragraph of first page in [On characterizations of atomistic lattices](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs000120050143.pdf)) asserts that this property is **upper-continuity**.  The most common definition of upper-continuity I've seen appears, e.g. in *Continuous lattices and domains* as the condition that $x \wedge  \bigvee D = \bigvee x  \wedge D$ for every  directed set $D$.  I could image these definitions being equivalent if, for example, it were true that every directed set in a complete lattices  contains a totally ordered subset (chain) with equal supremum.  Not convinced that this is the case, however.

Property 2: If $L$ is a semi-ortholattice under the relation  $x \perp y  \iff x \wedge y = 0$, and **if** one can use chain and directed set interchangeably in this context, as with upper-continuity, then $L$ has this property iff it is **ortho-continuous** (see Maeda and Maeda, Theory of Symmetric Lattices, p9).

**Question 2**

Property 1: The notion of upper-continuity applies to all complete lattices.

Property 2: Every modular lattice is a semi-ortholattice under the relation $x \perp y  \iff x \wedge y = 0$.